# Disabling Natural Language Input in browser Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, input, natural-language

After a year or so I just came back to Wolfram Alpha Notebooks.

But it seems that the default for inserting new cells is now NaturalLanguageInput.

This is quite cumbersome as I can't even write a script as I used to, and variables are not maintained in scope.

Is there a way to go back to "normal" input without all the LM fuss?

Comment: "[...] without all the LM fuss?" -- Do you mean: "without the Large Language Model (LLM) fuss" ?